# Trying to do slow scrolling, but it seems gsap can't handle as many events per scroll

Tags: vue.js, scroll, gsap

I need to slow down scroll speed on the page to animate elements better (For example one wheel event on mine laptop makes deltaY = 378 and it's too hard to calculate correct offset to start animations). I decided to disable scroll with e.preventDefault() and e.returnValue = false. It works well, but sometimes page starts 'jumping', when u try to scroll.

```
import { gsap } from 'gsap'
import { ScrollToPlugin } from 'gsap/src/ScrollToPlugin.js'

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollToPlugin);


export default {
    data: () => {
        return {
            currentSlide: 0,
            offsetTop: 0,
            pageHeight: 0,
            wheelCounter: 0,
            scrollCounter: 0,
            slides: [
                {
                    id: 'ad1',
                    bg: '/hall.jpg'
                },
                {
                    id: 'ad2',
                    bg: '/home.jpg'
                },
                {
                    id: 'ad3',
                    bg: '/hall.jpg'
                },
                {
                    id: 'ad4',
                    bg: '/home.jpg'
                }]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        checkScroll (event) {
            event.returnValue = false
            event.preventDefault()
            let sliderGap = 300
            let current, next
            let tl = gsap.timeline()
            this.wheelCounter += parseInt(event.deltaY / 5)
            if (this.wheelCounter < 0) this.wheelCounter = 0
            gsap.to(window, {scrollTo: this.wheelCounter, duration: 0.2})
            current = parseInt(this.wheelCounter / sliderGap)
            if (current > 4) current = 4
            if ((current != this.currentSlide) && (current < 4)) {
                document.getElementById('main').style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + this.slides[current].bg + '")'
                tl.to('#' + this.slides[this.currentSlide].id, {x: 20, opacity: 0, duration: 0.3})
                tl.to('#' + this.slides[current].id, {x: -20, opacity: 1, duration: 0.7})
                this.currentSlide = current
            }
            if (window.scrollY > 300) {
                tl.to('#about_header', {x: 0, opacity: 1, duration: 0.7})
                tl.to('#about_description', {y: 0, opacity: 1, duration: 0.7}, 0.5)
                tl.to('#about_picture', {x: 0, opacity: 1, duration: 1}, 0.5)
            }
            if (window.scrollY > 500) {
                tl.to('#left_offer', {y: 0, opacity: 1, duration: 1}, 0)
                tl.to('#right_offer', {y: 0, opacity: 1, duration: 1}, 0.5)
                tl.to('#offers_description', {x: 0, opacity: 1, duration: 0.5}, 1.5)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I thought about adding vue-observe-visibility package and perform animation via it. But scroll should be smooth too and idk how can I do it.

Comment: With this setup you will have conflicting animations. It's unclear what your end goal is but most likely you'll need to either detect if something is animating and don't animate or force the new animations to override the old ones.

Comment: Problem isn't in animations conflict. Scrolling is smooth and everything works well. Sometimes onwheel event isn't work, that is the problem